# Excel getting a runtime error 13: Type mismatch

Tags: vba, excel

Got this error:

```
Sub Namecheck()
Dim FirstName As Range, LastName As Range, fnamex As Range
Dim LNCount As Double
Dim lname As Variant, fname As Variant, lname2 As Variant
Dim i As Integer, p1 As Integer

i = 1

Set FirstName = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sheet1).Range("B2:B47175")
Set LastName = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sheet1).Range("C2:C47175")

For Each lname In LastName
    i = 1 + i
    LNCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(LastName, lname)
        If LNCount > 2 Then
            p1 = 1
            fname = cell.Offset(0, -1).Value
            Set fnamex = FirstName.Find(what:=fname, Lookat:=xlWhole)
                If Not fnamex Is Nothing Then
                ActiveCell.Cells = fnamex.Address
                lname2 = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
                    If lname2 = lname Then
                    ActiveCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 36
                    End If
                End If
        End If

Next

End Sub
```

Any ideas?

Comment: its a sort of duplicate checking code...you can probably figure that from the poorly written code.

Comment: in what line do you get an error?

Comment: should it be `ActiveCell.Value = fnamex.Address` instead `ActiveCell.Cells = fnamex.Address`? and where `cell` come from: `fname = cell.Offset(0, -1).Value`?

Comment: Set FirstName = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sheet1).Range("B2:B47175")

Comment: change `Sheets(Sheet1)` to `Sheets("Sheet1")`

Comment: that fixed that, i forgot abt the ""

Comment: but now the cell bit i was trying to select a cell with that obviously wrong there...much thanks for ur help.

Comment: can you expalin what your code should do? it's little bit messy now..

Comment: its supposed to look in lastname range to see there are more than one occurrence for each name; if there is one then check the first name on that row to see the next occurrence of the first name has the same last name as before. if it does then the cell color is 36.

Comment: what if you have 3 or more records with same lastname and firstname? the all should be colored?

Comment: yeah in that case all three would need to be colored.

Comment: one more question, you said `to see there are more than one occurrence for each name` but used `If LNCount > 2 Then`..why not `If LNCount > 1 Then`?

Comment: ah another mistake, you sir have a good eye. I'm learning...this is my first attempt at a serious code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Non VBA solution.**

use [Conditional formatting](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/use-a-formula-to-apply-conditional-formatting-HA102809768.aspx):

**Step1:**

Select entire columns `B:C` (if you want to color only one column, select only it, e.g. select column `B` for highlighting only firstnames). With selected columns go to *Conditional Formatting --> New Rule..*

[image]

**Step2:**

Select *Use a formula to detect which cells to format*, enter formula `=COUNTIFs($B:$B,$B1,$C:$C,$C1)>1` and choose desired format. Press OK.

[image]

**Result:**

[image]

---

**VBA solution**

```
Sub Namecheck()
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim lname As Range

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        Set rng = .Range("B2:C" & lastrow)
    End With
    For Each lname In rng.Columns(2).Cells
        If Application.CountIfs(rng.Columns(2), lname, rng.Columns(1), lname.Offset(, -1)) > 1 Then
            lname.Interior.ColorIndex = 36 'change color of lastname
            lname.Offset(, -1).Interior.ColorIndex = 36 'change color of firstname
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: muchas gracias simoco